# Subdomain and sockets

Tags: c, sockets, http, subdomain, posix

I'm trying to write a simple application to make a http get request on a site. which will then put some values in the database. However im stuck at the very beginning already.

Im trying to access a subdomain (Not sure if thats what it is called) and then write a get command to it. However i can not seem to connect to the website, since the ip i get is obviously from the main site. Eventually what i want is to execute the following:

"http://innoseis.freeiz.com/mysql.php?sensorValue=12"

where the sensorvalue is the http get.

However im first trying to connect and get the http body from www.innoseis.freeiz.com, could somebody give me some pointers in the right direction? I tried searching for subdomain sockets on google, but without avail. Thanks very much :)

My code so far (assembled from some tutorial):

http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/1VK6

**edit**
Trying to fiddle around a bit with telnet doesnt bring results

```
telnet www.innoseis.freeiz.com 80
Trying 31.170.161.216...
```

Connected to www.innoseis.freeiz.com.

Escape character is '`^]`'.

```
GET /mysql.php?sensorValue=12 HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: www.innoseis.freeiz.com\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
^]
```

*(long wait)*

```
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "*(sub-)domain socket*". There are "*UNIX domain sockets*" but this is a different story not related to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: if you want to do a simple webrequest don't do it via sockets but use httpclient

Comment: @PhilipStuyck: Being somewhat more specific would be much more helpfull.

Comment: What is the preamble called then? so innoseis is a part of freeiz domains right?
Also i cant use httpclients

Comment: @alk, I did not notice .NET was not in the picture here. It has to be c.

Comment: the point remains, that there might be libraries available that can do a get request. libwww comes to mind for C++ but i am not sure if that is an option. Doing everything via a socket is a bit cumbersome. You have to go through a lot of hastle.

Comment: you have fiddler ? do the request manually and see what fiddler sends. You have to do the exact same thing. http is very strict you might simply need to send \r\n once more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please post a minimal complete verifiable example of the code as in-line code, not as a link.

That said, what you want to do is to get the IP of innoseis.freeiz.com, and then connect to that IP, port 80. Then you send the following request:

```
GET /mysql.php?sensorValue=12 HTTP/1.1
Host: innoseis.freeiz.com
Connection: close
```

So, the subdomain is specified as the Host header in the HTTP protocol.

Comment: But isnt freeiz.com the host here? I've been trying to fiddle a little with telnet, but nothing rewlly works there sadly enough.

    telnet www.innoseis.freeiz.com 80
Trying 31.170.161.216...
Connected to www.innoseis.freeiz.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /mysql.php?sensorValue=12 HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: www.innoseis.freeiz.com\r\n


Connection: close\r\n


^]

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this I would suggest the following.
Install fiddler on your pc. I hope you can use this otherwise use a different pc.
Do the request you want to do manually but enable fiddler.
Using fiddler you get to see exactly what the browser is sending and you need to do the same thing in your code. Some fields are less important but `HTTP` is pretty strict on some things like linefeeds and such.

It might be that you are only missing a simple `\r\n` carriage return linefeed to end your request to the server because of the `HTTP` protocol specifics.